# Why isn't my Operator Extra Link showing in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

Using this as a reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/define_extra_link.html

I can not get links to show in the UI. I have tried adding the link within the operator itself and building the separate extra_link.py file to add it and the link doesn't show up when looking at the task in graph or grid view. Here is my code for creating it in the operator:

```
class upstream_link(BaseOperatorLink):
    """Create a link to the upstream task"""
    name = "Test Link"

    def get_link(self, operator, *, ti_key):

        return "https://www.google.com"

# Defining the plugin class
class AirflowExtraLinkPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "integration_links"
    operator_extra_links = [
        upstream_link(),
    ]

class BaseOperator(BaseOperator, SkipMixin, ABC):
    """ Base Operator for all integrations """

    operator_extra_links = (upstream_link(),)
```

This is a custom BaseOperator class used by a few operators in my deployment. I don’t know if the inheritance is causing the issue or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, the goal is to have this on mapped tasks, this does work with mapped tasks right?

Edit: Here is the code I used when i tried the stand alone file approach in the plugins folder:

```
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperatorLink
from plugins.operators.integrations.base_operator import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

class upstream_link(BaseOperatorLink):
    """Create a link to the upstream task"""
    name = "Upstream Data"
    operators = [BaseOperator]

    def get_link(self, operator, *, ti_key):
        return "https://www.google.com"

# Defining the plugin class
class AirflowExtraLinkPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "extra_link_plugin"
    operator_extra_links = [
        upstream_link(),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the inheritance. Attaching the extra link does not carry through to the children as it seems that Airflow is just looking for that specific operator name. Extra Links also do not seem to work with mapped tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The custom plugins should be defined in the plugins folder (by default `$AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins`) to be processed by the plugin manager.

Try to create a new script in the plugins folder, and move `AirflowExtraLinkPlugin` class to this script, it should work.

Comment: I did that approach as well, following the guide in the link above. I was able to recover the code i had an will update the above post with what i used for the plugin folder approach

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked. I am even creating links dinamically. Thanks!